# Aptana php server debug mode opens empty page in firefox

Tags: php, debugging, drupal, aptana

I am using Aptana 3 studio to work on my php (drupal) projects. All of the sudden, the debug function stopped working. It *used* to work flawlessly. Now when I select a debug configurtion and debug it, an empty page opens in firefox. 
Is this connected with how Aptana communicates with the  browser? With the server?...

EDIT:
So I decided to try a new thing altogether and installed a full new system based on LXLE 14.04 (based on the same ubuntu 14.04, which I used in a full unity version before). 
Now, after some quirks, I have a running debug in Aptana on that system. I am pretty sure, though, that this is the configuration that worked for me in the first place. 
I also remarked some weird window behavior on the system - sometimes the Aptana window would get so small it is hardly noticable (1px*1px?) and gets to the top left corner.

Answer (score 0):

I found that setting xdebug.remote_autostart=1 in php.ini and restarting Apache allows me to debug somewhat. Although Firefox still opens a blank page, opening the page myself in the browser now allows me to get a break in Aptana.